# Index exceeding matrix dimensions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2015b and I keep getting an issue where my index thinks it's too big for the matrix dimensions. Here is my code:

```
fid = fopen('GPS.dat');
m = 0;
r = 6371;
while feof(fid) == 0
    m = m + 1;
    GPS = fgetl(fid);
    [x,GPS2] = strtok(GPS,' '); 
    [y,GPS3] = strtok(GPS2,' '); 
    [z,GPS4] = strtok(GPS3,' '); 
    [GPSweek,GPS5] = strtok(GPS4,' ');
    [GPSsecondintoweek] = strtok(GPS5,' '); 
end
for i = 1:m 
    if x(i) == 0 && y(i) == 0
        lon(i) = 0;
    elseif x(i) ~= 0 
        lon(i) = atand(y(i)/x(i));
    end
    if z(i) ~= 0
        lat(i) = asind((z(i))/r);
    else
        lat(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

The code is supposed to take cartesian coodinates from a .dat file and turn them into Longitude and Latitude.  The code works all the way up till the second iteration of the for loop, when i = 2.  This confuses me because the dat file has 6 vectors, so m = 6, so it should be able to go up to 6.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To understand your issue, set a breakpoint to the `GPS = fgetl(fid);` line and take a look what happens in the following lines when you reach it the second time. You already have something stored in `x` but you write again to `x` overwriting the previous content. Instead you have to use indices like you did in the for loop.

Comment: See: [`dbstop if error`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html#buzezti-1). Your data does not have the shape you are expecting.